# Mouse Event Click Problems

Tags: actionscript-3, switch-statement, mouseevent, gsap, flash-cc

When you click the ageImg button(the pink image in the swf) it calls the next function which is supposed to hide all of the other images and moves the ageism word up onto the stage but for some reason after one second it goes blank and the ageFlash function starts again causing the entire animation to start from the beginning. I dont know why it loops.

[[LINK TO SWF FILE]](http://www.swfcabin.com/open/1413555536)

```
import com.greensock.TweenLite;
import com.greensock.TimelineLite;
import com.greensock.plugins.*;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var ageismTimeline:TimelineLite = new TimelineLite();

       function init():void{
            ageFlash();
            ageImg.ageism.visible=false;
            racImg.racism.visible=false;
            hatImg.hate.visible=false;
            sexImg.sexism.visible=false;
         }


        function ageFlash():void{
            ageImg.visible=false;
            ageImg.buttonMode = true;
            ageImg.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopPicLoop);
            TweenLite.delayedCall(1,racFlash);
         }

         function racFlash():void{
            racImg.visible=false;
            TweenLite.delayedCall(1,hatFlash);
         }

         function hatFlash():void{
            hatImg.visible=false;
            TweenLite.delayedCall(1,sexFlash);
         }

         function sexFlash():void{
            TweenLite.delayedCall(1,ageFlash);
            ageImg.visible=true;
            racImg.visible=true;
            hatImg.visible=true;
         }

         function stopPicLoop(event:MouseEvent):void{
                switch (event.type) {

                       case "click":

                          trace(event.type);
                              ageAni();

                              break;

                       case 2:

                              break;

                       case 3:

                              break;

                }
          }

          function ageAni():void{
            racImg.visible=false;
            hatImg.visible=false;
            sexImg.visible=false;
            ageImg.visible=true;
            ageImg.ageism.visible=true;
            ageismTimeline.from(ageImg.ageism,.5,{y:stage.stageHeight});

            trace('ageism');
         }
init();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to kill off the delayed call to the `racFlash` method you set up in the `ageFlash` method otherwise your code will continue on its merry way. You can use the `TweenLite.killDelayedCallsTo` method to do this (see [documentation](http://www.greensock.com/asdocs/com/greensock/TweenLite.html)):

```
function ageAni():void{
    racImg.visible=false;
    hatImg.visible=false;
    sexImg.visible=false;
    ageImg.visible=true;
    ageImg.ageism.visible=true;

    TweenLite.killDelayedCallsTo(racFlash); // kill the delayed call
    ageismTimeline.from(ageImg.ageism,.5,{y:stage.stageHeight});

    trace('ageism');
}
```